# Difference between "at date" and "to date"

Tags: meaning, grammar, vocabulary

Two Examples:

> - It is the social networking giant's biggest acquisition **to date**.
> - The deal to buy it includes $4bn in cash... plus an additional $3 billion in stock to WhatsApp's founders and employees **at a later date.**

Comment: *To date* is 'short' for up until this date (which in this context means today.) *At a later date* means some time in the future (a date later than today.)

Answer (score 1):

- *to date* refers to the period of time which has occured until now.

> I have collected 150 stamps to date.

- *at (some) date* refers to the date mentioned. In your case, it says, 'at a later date', which means at some point in the future, i.e. some point in time *later*.

> I will do the project at a later date.